# Goroutines: Where to close

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I am struggling to understand where I should close my channels.

This bit of code takes about 0.7 seconds:

```golang
options := [3]string{"0", "1", "2"}
str := fmt.Sprintf("%6d ", id)
for j := 0; j < 40000; j++ {
    str += options[rand.Intn(3)]
}
str += "\n"
```

Adding an io.Writestring does not make a difference to the time, so the problem is this bit.

I want roughly 100,000 records like these so I thought to put in a goroutine.

```
func main() {
    file, _ := os.Create("myfile.txt")
    ch := make(chan string)
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
       go generate(i, ch)
    }

    counter := 0
    for result := range ch {
       counter++
       io.WriteString(file, result)
       if counter == 100000 {
           close(ch)
       }
    }
    file.Close()
}

func generate(id int, c chan string) {
    options := [3]string{"0", "1", "2"}
    str := fmt.Sprintf("%6d ", id)
    for j := 0; j < 40000; j++ {
        str += options[rand.Intn(3)]
    }
    str += "\n"
    c <- str
}
```

From what I understand is that I am closing the channel on the receiver side, which is not ideal? Also, this way all 100,000 should be sent to goroutines first, before I can receive any. Can I send requests to generate a record and start receiving at the same time?

Comment: You should close on the sender side, when the sender will not be sending any more values. You can send and receive at the same time (in separate goroutines). You can close before all values have been received from a buffered channel also, the buffered values will still be receieved. Please see the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2).

Comment: And in cases where there are more than one sender (like here), use a [sync.WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) and a separate goroutine that closes the channel when the WaitGroup is done.

Comment: Does the solution help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a counter to close your channel is not a good practise.You can make use of `sync.WaitGroup`. This allows you to have a better control on when to close your channel:

```
func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    ch := make(chan string)
    file, _ := os.Create("myfile.txt")

    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()

            options := [3]string{"0", "1", "2"}
            str := fmt.Sprintf("%6d ", i)
            for j := 0; j < 40000; j++ {
                str += options[rand.Intn(3)]
            }
            str += "\n"
            ch <- str
        }(i)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()

    for result := range ch {
        io.WriteString(file, result)
    }
    file.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this solves your problem..

```
func main() {
    file, _ := os.Create("myfile.txt")
    ch := make(chan string)
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
       wg.Add(1)
       go generate(i, ch)
    }

    go func(){wg.Wait();close(ch)}()

    counter := 0
    for result := range ch {
       counter++
       io.WriteString(file, result)

    }
    file.Close()
}

func generate(id int, c chan string) {
    options := [3]string{"0", "1", "2"}
    str := fmt.Sprintf("%6d ", id)
    for j := 0; j < 40000; j++ {
        str += options[rand.Intn(3)]
    }
    str += "\n"
    c <- str
    wg.Done()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I am not sure if I understand correctly: I placed a print statement right before `go func() {wg.Wait()...}`. It seems that print is done only after all 100000 have been sent to `go generate()`?